# ASP.NET MVC: How to 'model bind' a non html-helper element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, model-binding

Could you tell me a way(s) that I can bind a **model** property to a html-element, created without using html helper?

In other words to a plain html element such as: `<input type="text" />`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are referring to [Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx), it does not require helpers, but naming convention. Helpers just make it easy and concise to create the HTML markup.

You could create plain HTML inputs and just set the `name` attribute correctly. The default naming convention is just dot based, omitting the parent level entity's name, but qualifying it from there.

Consider this controller:

```
public class MyControllerController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Submit()
     {
         return View(new MyViewModel());
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Submit(MyViewModel model)
     {
            // model should be not null, with properties properly initialized from form values
            return View(model);
     }
}
```

And this model:

```
public class MyNestedViewModel
{
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
         Nested = new MyNestedViewModel();
    }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public MyNestedViewModel Nested  { get; set; }
}
```

You could create the following form purely in HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="MyController/Submit">
    <div><label>Some property</label><input type="text" name="SomeProperty" /></div>
    <div><label>Another property</label><input type="text" name="Nested.AnotherProperty" /></div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you want to display the posted values (in the second `Submit` overload), your HTML will have to be modified render the model properties. You'd place this in a view, in this case using Razor syntax and called `Submit.cshtml`:

```
@model MyViewModel
<form method="POST" action="MyController/Submit">
    <div><label>Some property</label><input type="text" name="SomeProperty" value="@Model.SomeProperty" /></div>
    <div><label>Another property</label><input type="text" name="Nested.AnotherProperty" value="@Model.Nested.SomeProperty" /></div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So, this can be done without helpers, but you'd want to use them as much as possible.

Comment: Nicely put Mike! Well my idea was to assign/bind a **model property** of a **model class/object** to a html-element with the real objective of performing **server side model base validation**. So having the correct text in the **html name attribute** is all that it requires to make the link between the html-element and the model property ? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! In order to get the binder to populate the value, yes, all you need is the `name` attribute to match the property on the class. Model binders will also do validation, too. For example, Data Annotations are supported out of the box (and you can extend these with your own validators, client-side, too), so if you start decorating your properties with these attributes, it'll check those for you, too. I'm sure you know your own project best, but none of this should preclude you from using helpers (just encouraging you to use them, since they cut down on errors and manual labor).

Comment: Point taken. Well I too prefer to use the helpers, may be I'm seen this wrong, but what makes me to take a different path is that: the use of **certain jQuery controls**. For example some jQuery control's data assignment, data validation and reading takes explicit routines. In those situations can we use these default helpers? Thanks again Mike!

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I suppose it depends on the jQuery control.

Comment: Thanks again Mike! Great help! :)

Comment: @HackedByChinese: how can I populate checkboxes with jQuery and bind it to model ? I am able to create and render checkboxes successfully, but when data gets postback to server, it dosen't preserve the value of checkbox ? Any !dea ?

Comment: @ITppl It'd be best to start a new question, so you can post the client and server-side code you're using.

Comment: @HackedByChinese : Can you please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702721/preserve-dynamically-generated-check-boxs-value-on-postback

Comment: @HackedByChinese Can you explain how to use `<select multiple>` elemene instead of  `@Html.ListBoxFor` in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 8):

Just give it a name:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" />
```

and then inside your controller action simply have an argument with the same name:

```
public ActionResult Process(string foo)
{
    // The foo argument will contain the value entered in the 
    // corresponding input field
}
```

Comment: A very important thing to note is that when you pass JSON objects via JQuery, the variable's name also needs to be the same as the method parameter.

Comment: Well, actually that's not quite true. If you use a view model (which you should always be doing anyway) and not specify a root property in your JSON object like `{"foo":"bar","baz":"bazinga"}` you could name your variable however you like and the model binder will happily bind the properties of the view model: `public ActionResult(MyViewModel nobodyCaresHowThisVariableIsName) { ... }`

Comment: See this question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953296/similar-json-requests-but-one-sends-null-object

Comment: @JuannStrauss, this problem of yours is the fact that you have a property in your view model which has the same name as the action argument. And this has been like that since ASP.NET MVC 1. It has nothing to do with JSON. This code will also break with a standard HTML form submit.