# How to bind html controls without using ASP.Net MVC html helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in MVC. i have seen in mvc people generate html this way and bind data also

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => p.Name, "Name:")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => p.Name)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

but if i do not want to use html helper extension then how should i code to bind normal html controls and forms with model data. please come with a sample code. thanks

Comment: If you don't want to use MVC helpers to correctly create html input controls, why are you using MVC?  I don't see any good reason to make life harder writing html to correclty bind models.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `name` attribute of `input`  controls to match your model property name.

For Example in your current case if you want to replace `TextBoxFor()` with `input` control, do like this:

### TextBox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Name)
<input name="Name" type="Text" value="@Model.Name"/>
```

### DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SomeProperty,ItemsList)

<select name="SomePropertyType">
<option value="someValue">Some Text</option>
</select>
```

The same way we have to do for DropDown List case.

### @Html.BeginForm():

```
@using(Html.BeginFor("ActionName","ControllerName",FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```

in HTML For form, you have to use form tag:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")" method="post">

</form>
```

### UPDATE:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.SomeProperty")
```

in html as:

```
<input id="SomeProperty" name="SomeProperty" type="text" value="@Model.SomeProperty" />

@Html.TextAreaFor("SomeName", "", 10, 50, null)
```

in html as :

```
<textarea cols="50" id="SomeName" name="SomeName" rows="10">
```

### PasswordFor:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.SomeProperty)
```

in html as:

```
<input id="SomeProperty" name="SomeProperty" type="password" />
```

See [this article of Scottgu for reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios) and also [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/794579/ASP-NET-MVC-HTML-Helpers-A-MUST-KNOW)

Comment: thanks for answer. it would be helpfull for me like starter in mvc if you would come with each different type of html control with model binding syntax.

Comment: you said "You have to use name attribute of input controls to match your model property name" can't we use ID attribute instead of Name attribute ? why name attribute is important in mvc instead of id attribute ?

Comment: @Mou I will surely add, I am currently posting from my tab, so it's a bit difficult to write in detail but I try to add

Comment: No @Mou you can test that , name attribute is mapped in post to model

Comment: can u plzz redirect me to right article which discuss why people need to use name attribute in mvc instead of id attribute for model binding? thanks

Comment: see this SO post as reference:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353245/asp-net-mvc-how-to-model-bind-a-non-html-helper-element I will share article if I find some

Comment: `can't we use ID attribute instead of Name attribute ?` No, this has never been the case, and will never be the case.  The World Wide Web Consort Consortium has never changed the fact that - [When a form is submitted for processing, some controls have their name paired with their current value and these pairs are submitted with the form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html).

Comment: No, you cannot use the ID.  The reason is that your web browser does not use the ID to submit form data, it only uses the name.  This is the purpose of the name attribute, specifically for form submission.  You can't change this, as it's the HTML standard.  This has nothing to do with MVC, and it works this way for all HTML frameworks.  The browser simply will not work any other way.  I suggest you learn more about HTML and HTTP, as this knowledge is invaluable in understanding the details of MVC.